# React useState and History.push issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs

im working on a react app,and I came up with the following issue:
Im triyng to simulate the registration process of a new user. For that a have a funtion, called HandleRegister,it goes through the users array and validates that the new user´s name doesn't already exists, then if everything goes well,it sholud register it and redirect to /login, if there is an error the Failed state should update, re-rendering the component and showing the div that contains an alert message
The problems is the following: no matter the result of the validation, it is redirecting me to /login and adding the new user to the array
here is the code for **RegisterPage.js**

```
    import { React, useState } from "react";
import { useHistory } from "react-router";
import useAuth from "../../auth/useAuth";
export default function RegisterPage() {
  const auth = useAuth();
  const [newUserName, setnewUserName] = useState("");
  const [newUserPassword, setnewUserPassword] = useState("");
  const [Failed, setFailed] = useState(false);
  const updateNewUserName = (e) => setnewUserName(e.target.value);
  const updateNewUserPassword = (e) => setnewUserPassword(e.target.value);
  const history = useHistory();
  const HandleRegister = async () => {
    var Users = auth.getUsers();
    Users.forEach(({ username }) => {
      if (username === newUserName) {
        setFailed(true);
      }
    });

    if (Failed) {
      console.log("Error!");
    } else {
      auth.setUsers(newUserName, newUserPassword);
      setnewUserName("");
      setnewUserPassword("");
      history.push("/login");
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {Failed && (
        <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
          This username already exist!
        </div>
      )}
      <h1>Register</h1>
      <form className="form-control">
        <label for="username" className="form-check-label">
          Usuario
        </label>
        <input
          id="username"
          placeholder="username"
          className="form-check-input"
          type="text"
          className="form-control"
          value={newUserName}
          onChange={updateNewUserName}
        ></input>
        <label for="password" className="form-check-label">
          Contraseña
        </label>
        <input
          id="password"
          placeholder="password"
          className="form-check-input"
          type="text"
          className="form-control"
          value={newUserPassword}
          onChange={updateNewUserPassword}
        ></input>
        <button
          type="button"
          className="btn btn-primary m-2"
          onClick={HandleRegister}
        >
          REGISTER
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**UseAuth** is a hook for consuming a **AuthProvider** Context

AuthProvider.js code :

```
import { createContext,useState,useEffect,useContext } from "react";
export const AuthContext = createContext();
export const UsersContext = createContext();

const AuthProvider = ({children}) =>{
    const [user, setUser] = useState(
        JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user")) || null
    );
    useEffect(()=>{
        try {
            localStorage.setItem("user",JSON.stringify(user));
            
        } catch (error) {
            localStorage.removeItem("user")
            console.log(error)
        }
    },[user])
    const contextValue={
        user,
        login(user,password){setUser({username:user,password:password})} //en realidad este seria el ultimo paso,caso real consumir api => consultar => validar 
        ,
        logout(){
            setUser(null);
        }, 
        getUsers(){
            var Users= JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("users")) || [] 
            if(!(Users instanceof Array)) Users = [Users]; 
            return Users
       },
       setUsers(newName,newPass){

        var Users = this.getUsers()
        Users.push({username:newName,password:newPass}); 
        Users = Users.filter(Boolean)
        localStorage.setItem("users", JSON.stringify(Users));

       },
       islogged(){
            return !! user;
        }
    }


    return <AuthContext.Provider value={contextValue}>
        {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>

}


export default AuthProvider;
```

**UseAuth.js** code

```
import {useContext} from 'react'
import { AuthContext } from './AuthProvider'

export default function useAuth() {
    const contextValue = useContext(AuthContext);
    return contextValue
}
```

the weird thing is a came up with a similar solution for the login validation process, that works as intended

**Login.js** code

```
import { React, useState } from "react";
import { useHistory, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import useAuth from "../../auth/useAuth";

const LoginPage = () => {
  const auth = useAuth();
  const history = useHistory();
  const location = useLocation();
  const [User, setUser] = useState(null);
  const [Password, setPassword] = useState(null);
  const [Failed, setFailed] = useState(false);
  const updateUser = (e) => setUser(e.target.value);
  const updateUserPassword = (e) => setPassword(e.target.value);

  const handleLogin = () => {
    var Users = auth.getUsers();
    Users.forEach(async ({ username, password }) => {
      if (username === User && password === Password) {
        await auth.login(User, Password);
        setFailed(false);
        history.push(location.state?.from || "/");
      }
    });
    setFailed(true);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      {Failed && (
        <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
          Wrong Username or password!
        </div>
      )}

      <div class="col-md-4 mx-auto">
        <div class="card mt-4 text-center carta">
          <div class="card-header  carta-header">
            <h1>Login</h1>
          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <form>
              <div class="mt-3">
                <input
                  class="input form-control"
                  type="text"
                  name="code"
                  placeholder="username"
                  value={User}
                  onChange={updateUser}
                />
              </div>
              <div class="mt-3">
                <input
                  class="input form-control"
                  type="password"
                  name="code"
                  placeholder="***"
                  value={Password}
                  onChange={updateUserPassword}
                />
              </div>
              <div class="mt-3">
                <button
                  class=" btn btn-primary tamaño"
                  type="button"
                  id="submit"
                  onClick={handleLogin}
                >
                  <span>GO</span> <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
                </button>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
export default LoginPage;
```

I´made some tests and if I use a regular variable (not a react state) to manage the Failure of the register process it works as it should, but i dont think thats the ideal way of dealing with this.
what would be the best way to code this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that `useState` [is Asynchronous](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous), so when you use `if (username === newUserName) {setFailed(true);}`, `Failed` will be true just after re-render the component, to avoid that, try this code :

```
const HandleRegister = async () => {
    const failed = false;
    var Users = auth.getUsers();
    Users.forEach(({ username }) => {
      if (username === newUserName) {
        failed = true;
      }
    });

    if (failed ) {
      console.log("Error!");
    } else {
      auth.setUsers(newUserName, newUserPassword);
      setnewUserName("");
      setnewUserPassword("");
      history.push("/login");
     //for me, I prefer in this case use history.replace instead of history.push
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

SetState actions are asynchronous. When you do setFailed(true) and immediately check the value of Failed, the value of Failed will not have changed yet.